# WP7 - Splash Screen doesn't display correctly on launch

Tags: image, splash-screen, windows-phone-7

**What I'm trying to do:**

I've added a splash screen to an application I'm creating for Windows Phone 7. I did this simply by replacing the pre-existing splash screen file with my own.

**What goes wrong:**

The splash screen is not displayed like it should be - it is being down sampled to an 8 bit image or something weird:

-

*The image I'm using*

[image: Splash Screen]

-

*The image that gets displayed*

[image: Splash Screen - bad]

It's a bit hard to see depending on your monitor, but on a phone it's reasonably obvious. There are fuzzy greenish lines that appear - basically like the image is being down sampled or the quality worsened.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong, or what might be happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try forcing the app to display images at 32 bits per pixel (instead of the default of 16)

Add an attribute of `BitsPerPixel="32"` to the app element in WMAppManifest.xml
See http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/85960/520394.aspx#520394

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this later and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: This definitely fixes the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the gradient on your splash screen is causing banding, which you can solve by dithering. Robby Ingebretsen has an action for PhotoShop that you can use: http://nerdplusart.com/photoshop-action-for-windows-phone-7-dithering

Comment: Thanks - although this doesn't really seem to help... it might be slightly better but the banding is still there. The weird thing is that for the first second or so it displays fine, and then for the next second or so it switches to the ugly graphics mode. Does this sound like it's the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the emulator. Run the emulator at full size or run the app on an actual device.

Comment: Thanks, but it displays exactly the same on an actual phone - I tried this first.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phone is currently only supporting a color depth of 16bit, causing especially some gradients displaying downsampled for 24bit images. Some first generation firmwares by HTC had a "bug" that also allowed 24bit. Theoretically it is just a registry key, but you cannot commonly change it. Microsoft has limited the color depth to 16bit for the benefit of performance, but as far as I knnow there are some second-generation models without this limitation now.

You may try to downsample the image in Photoshop to 16bit and optimize it for this color depth.